# Change value to property that been received as @input property - Angular 7

Tags: angular

Is it possible to reassign value from child component for a property that i'm receiving as a `@Input` from parent component?

As I see it is not possible if so, so why? it's just a reference, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it is exactly that you mean, but I'll answer how I understood it ;)

@Input is a one way communication. So if `parent.component` sends an Input into `child.component` and you reassign it in `child.component`, `parent.component` has no knowledge about those changes. Any change in `parent.component` however, will override the value in `child.component` again.

If you do not want it to be overriden, you can either implement the `OnChange` interface and manually make sure it is not overridden anymore.

OR

Use the @Input value only as an initializer and keep the actual value in a variable in `child.component`, so in `ngOnInit` you'd do something along the likes of:

```
this.value = this.initializedValue;
```

and subsequently you only ever change this.value.

(If you want two-way binding, so changes in child are reflected in parent, just provide corresponding @Output, the shorthand [(variable)] actually stands for:

```
// Child component TS
@Input() variable: any;
@Output() variableChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

...

<!-- parent html -->
<app-child [(variable)]="parentVariable"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the value from the parent component, once you change the value, you ngOnChanges gets triggered on the child component, where you will get the updated value.